# Десериализация JSON в LiteDB

Tags: c#, json, десериализация

В проекте нужно из JSON-строки получить экземпляр некоторого класса, используя библиотеку `LiteDB`.
JSON:

```
{
   "field1": "string",
   "field2": 1
}
```

Классы устроены следующим образом:

```
class Class1
{
    public string field1;
    public int field2;
}
```

В классе-наследнике `LiteDatabase` определен следующий метод:

```
private T Read<T>(Stream inStream)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    inStream.CopyTo(ms);
    var bytes = ms.ToArray();
    ms.Dispose();
    var doc = BsonSerializer.Deserialize(bytes);
    return Mapper.ToObject<T>(doc);
}
```

Проблема в том, что при выполнении `BsonSerializer.Deserialize`вызывается исключение:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException не обработано пользовательским кодом
  HResult=-2146233080
Message=Индекс находился вне границ массива.
Source=LiteDB
StackTrace:
   в LiteDB.BsonReader.ReadCString(ByteReader reader)
   в LiteDB.BsonReader.ReadElement(ByteReader reader, String& name)
   в LiteDB.BsonReader.ReadDocument(ByteReader reader)
   в LiteDB.BsonSerializer.Deserialize(Byte[] bson)
```

Comment: Ну это нужно смотреть в документации на `LiteDB.BsonSerializer`, это ж нестандартный класс. Рискну предположить, что ваш текст представляет собой не BSON, а JSON (это не одно и то же).

Comment: Проверьте, есть ли что то в массиве `bytes`? Может это он пустой, и исключение из-за этого возникает

Comment: @Donil, массив `bytes` содержит элементы.